# C# I am having trouble with variables not acting as I would expect

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, int

I am trying to emulate a dice rolling and if the die lands on a certain number then it does something, and if it lands on another number it does something else. However, I am having trouble with this. Where it says `if (hitPoints = 1)` I am getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string.'

But you can clearly see that it is indeed a string. Any help on this problem would be very much appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
Random r = new Random();
    int hit = r.Next(1, 5);
    string hitPoints = hit.ToString();


    EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();



    if (hitPoints = 1)
    { 
        builder.WithTitle("");
    }
```

Comment: `if (hit == 1)` sorted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

I see you've declared and assigned `hitpoints` as a string:

```
string hitPoints = hit.ToString();
```

But below that you're comparing it (I hope) to a number:

```
if (hitPoints = 1)
```

There's two problems there.  First, that's not the comparison operator.  Second, the literal `1` is not a string.

If you truly want `hitPoints` to be a string, and you want to compare it to `1` then try this:

```
if (hitPoints == "1")
```

Side note: allow me to recommend that you don't store `hitPoints` as a string just to output it as one.  You can always call `.ToString()` on your existing `hit` variable:

```
int hit = r.Next(1, 5);

if (hit == 1) {
    // do a thing
}

// using newer string interpolation, implicit hit.ToString()
Console.WriteLine($"Hit was {hit}");

// using old format, implicit hit.ToString()
Console.WriteLine("Hit was {0}", hit);

// using old format, explicit hit.ToString()
Console.WriteLine("Hit was {0}", hit.ToString());
```